# How to draw resultant vector using the matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I even found the resultant vector and printed it's magnitude, but I can't plot it.

[image: current results]

Here is the code:
Here I am finding the resultant and which is correct but my graph is incorrect.
The output I am getting is at the end.

```
import numpy as np
a1=np.array([2,3])
a2=np.array([1,6])
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlim(-10,10)
plt.ylim(-10,10)
at=a1+a2
origin=np.array([0,0])
plt.quiver(*origin,at[0],at[1],scale=50)
plt.grid()
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.legend(['Vector Addition of two vectors'])
plt.show()
print(at)
m=np.linalg.norm(at)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.quiver.html) at the *scale_units* part :

> To plot vectors in the x-y plane, with u and v having the same units
> as x and y, use angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1.

So you can change your line to this :

```
plt.quiver(*origin, at[0], at[1], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1)
```

And you'll get this result :

[image: graph]

Which is pointing at the right place i.e. (3, 9).